# How can I use localStorage to make the browser remember a classlist toggle state for a light/dark mode theme switch?

Tags: javascript

I am a working on a portfolio website that has a light/darkmode theme switch. The switch works, but it does not save the input. So when the user refreshes or clicks on a navigation link, the website goes back to the default lightmode. I want it to remember the state. I know that I have to use localStorage to make it work, but I can not seem to figure out how to do it.

**Website:**
[www.hermanvulkers.com](http://www.hermanvulkers.com)

**JavaScript theme switch code:**

```
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (document.body.classList.contains("light-theme")) {
        // Turn light mode off -> dark mode on
        document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
        document.getElementById('themeswitcher').innerHTML = `<span>Dark</span><img src="images/moon.png" alt="Choose website theme">`;

    } else {
        // Turn dark mode off -> light mode on  
        document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
        document.getElementById('themeswitcher').innerHTML = `<span>Light</span><img src="images/sunrise.png" alt="Choose website theme"></img>`;
        
    }
});
```

**HTML button code:**

```
<button class="themeswitcher" id="themeswitcher">
    <span>Dark</span>
    <img src="images/moon.png" alt="Choose website theme">
</button>
```

Is anyone able to help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Your code is unnecessarily complex.

Here is a full version

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  const theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
  if (theme) document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme",theme==="light")
  document.getElementById("themeswitcher").addEventListener("click", function () {
    const light = document.body.classList.contains("light-theme")
    this.innerHTML = `<span>${light? 'Dark' : 'light'}</span><img src="images/${light? 'moon' : 'sunrise'}.png" alt="Choose website theme">`;
    document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
    localStorage.setItem("theme",light?"dark":"light");
  });
});
```

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot. It is really concise. Can anyone help me understand this line?  
if (theme) document.body.classList.toggle ("light-theme", theme === "light")

Comment: If there was a theme in the localStorage, toggle (add the class) if theme is "light" otherwise remove it

Comment: I wrapped the code in a "load" handler to make it easier to use external script

Comment: We can also just update the span text and the image source

Answer (score 2):

You can add it like this:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (document.body.classList.contains("light-theme")) {
        // Turn light mode off -> dark mode on
        window.localStorage.setItem('darkmodeTurnedOn', 'true');
        document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
        document.getElementById('themeswitcher').innerHTML = `<span>Dark</span><img src="images/moon.png" alt="Choose website theme">`;

    } else {
        // Turn dark mode off -> light mode on  
        document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
        window.localStorage.setItem('darkmodeTurnedOn', 'false');
        document.getElementById('themeswitcher').innerHTML = `<span>Light</span><img src="images/sunrise.png" alt="Choose website theme"></img>`;
        
    }
});
```

Also, on initial loading of your site, you should have listener to switch this on or off, like this:

```
<body onload="setTheme">
```

And in the setTheme function you can do the following:

```
function setTheme(){
  if (window.localStorage.getItem('darkmodeTurnedOn') === 'true'){
     document.body.classList.remove("light-theme");
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the first one I tried and for some reason it did not work for me. I have my JavaScript code in a separate component file. Is this a problem with the onload I have to use in the HTML file?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set an item into the localStorage with:

```
localStorage.setItem('key', value);
```

and then access it with

```
let value = localStorage.getItem('key');
```

So I think this should work:

```
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (document.body.classList.contains("light-theme")) {
        // Turn light mode off -> dark mode on
        document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
        document.getElementById('themeswitcher').innerHTML = `<span>Dark</span><img src="images/moon.png" alt="Choose website theme">`;
        window.localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'true');

    } else {
        // Turn dark mode off -> light mode on  
        document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
        document.getElementById('themeswitcher').innerHTML = `<span>Light</span><img src="images/sunrise.png" alt="Choose website theme"></img>`;
        window.localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'false');
        
    }
});
```

And somewhere in the beginning of your code:

```
let wasDarkMode = window.localStorage.getItem('darkMode');
if (wasDarkMode) {
document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
    

    document.getElementById('themeswitcher').innerHTML = `<span>Dark</span><img src="images/moon.png" alt="Choose website theme">`;
} else {
document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
            document.getElementById('themeswitcher').innerHTML = `<span>Light</span><img src="images/sunrise.png" alt="Choose website theme"></img>`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be used to set and retvie the switch state. Retrieve it when you need to check the state. Instead of "if (document.body.classList.contains("light-theme"))"
you should just use the localstorage state. Just set the default state to localstorage if it is null.

```
export const set = (key, value) => {
localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
};

export const retrieve = key => {
    try {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
} catch (error) {
    return null;
}
};

export const remove = key => localStorage.removeItem(key);

export const exists = key => localStorage.getItem(key) !== null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a theme switcher for two or more themes. Working with localstorage.
Tell me if it works great and if you have questions. :)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var themesList = ['dark-theme', 'light-theme', 'other-theme'];

    var theme = localStorage["theme"] || themesList[0]  /*if localStorage["theme"] exists || default is dark-theme*/;
    const updateTheme = (themeToUpdate = theme)=>{
        switch (themeToUpdate) {
            case 'light-theme':
                document.getElementById('themeswitcher').setAttribute('data-theme', themeToUpdate); // better to use data-* attributes for javascript use only
                document.getElementById('themeswitcher').innerHTML = `<span>Light</span><img src="images/sunrise.png" alt="Choose website theme">`;
            break;
            case 'dark-theme':
                document.getElementById('themeswitcher').setAttribute('data-theme', themeToUpdate);
                document.getElementById('themeswitcher').innerHTML = `<span>Dark</span><img src="images/moon.png" alt="Choose website theme">`;
            break;
            case 'other-theme':
                document.getElementById('themeswitcher').setAttribute('data-theme', themeToUpdate);
                document.getElementById('themeswitcher').innerHTML = `<span>Other</span><img src="whatever/you/want.png" alt="Choose website theme">`;
            break;
        
            default:
            break;
        }    
    } 
    updateTheme(theme);

    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
         let nextIndex = (themesList.indexOf(theme) >= themeList.length - 1) ? 0 : themesList.indexOf(theme) + 1;
        theme = themesList[nextIndex];
        localStorage["theme"] = theme;
        updateTheme(theme);
    });
});
```

Comment: Made a mistake on "nextIndex" you have to test if your themesList.indexOf(theme) >= themeList.length - 1 and set it back to 0

Comment: Something like this
let nextIndex = (themesList.indexOf(theme) >= themeList.length - 1) ?  0 : themesList.indexOf(theme) + 1;

Comment: please edit your post if you did a mistake and realized now

Comment: Please read the post before answering to my comments. It was edited.

Comment: why do you write here then if you already edited the answer ? its confusing

Comment: Look at edited time and comment time. I don't need someone to tell what to do. I can do it by myself. Writing it in a comment was a mistake to, but I assume it that's why i've left my comments.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. What I don’t like so much is the aggressive tone in the comments. We should be aware the we all make errors - also commenters, but we all try to help each other.

Comment: i am just trying to help the community by checking daily answers of new users. i wanted to inform that answers can be edited if any mistakes are made, and its confusing to check both comments and answer for a single solution. sory if i did any harm

Comment: Ali Fidanli, you've great intentions, but you seem to be annoyed by new users who don't match what you think is best for stackoverflow. This can distort your judgment and make it too hasty. It can respouss some new users, and no longer make them want to answer. It's not my case, but if it had been, I don't think it would have been good for stackoverflow.

Comment: I've to go, see you.

Comment: Thanks Reinhard Männer